# Cannot destructure property react.js useSelector

Tags: node.js, reactjs, toast, useselector

I have an error
Cnnot destructure property 'status' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.

I'm trying to handle errors that come from the server with "toast"
But when I wrote this code in RegisterPage.jsx, the page doesn't even open for me.

RegisterPage.jsx

```
const { status } = useSelector(state => state.auth )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (status) {
            toast(status)
        }
    }, [status])
```

store.js

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        auth: authSlice
    },
})
```

authSlice.js

```
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    isLoading: false,
    status: null,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by doing the following

```
const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth )

    useEffect(() => {
        if (auth?.status) {
            toast(auth?.status)
        }
    }, [auth?.status])
```

Most likely you are running react in strict mode and it renders twice/multiple times in strict mode. So, At first render you receive `undefined` at the end of these render you get the correct values.

Also, It runs twice/multiple times to detect side effects for you, it can help you spot errors by making it a little more deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like, something is wrong with the registering the slice. Change your code with below one and test.

Slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    isLoading: false,
    status: null,
}

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'authSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getUsers(state, action) {
      const { data, meta = {} } = action.payload;
      state.users = data;
    },
  }
});

export const { authSlice } = slice;


export default slice;
```

```
const { status = 'Something' } = useSelector(state => state.auth )
```

It's look like `state.auth` is not returning anything.